# Python Serial Port - unable to write data

Tags: python, serial-port

I am relatively new to Python. I wrote a script and need to add triggers that need to be send via an usb serial port to another pc. The problem is that the triggers (in this code example the 2) never show up on the software on the other pc. When I check it with the print() command, it does print a value, but the printed value is the same number for two different triggers. I have read other posts, I searched the internet, and I tried various things, but I didn't manage to resolve this iusse. This is the code I use for interfacing with the serial port (COM3).

```
#this part of code is defined at the beginning:
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(port=2, baudrate=9600)
ser.close()
#this part of the code later on to interface with the serial port:
ser.open()
ser.write(chr(2))
ser.close()
```

Maybe anyone here has any suggestions on where the problem could be? Thanks!

Comment: try adding `timeout=0` as a paramater to `serial.Serial`

Comment: i tried it with the timeout and writeTimeout command with different values, but that didn't have any effect

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, check that the port settings are correct, 9600,8,N,1 for example. These must match the settings of the remote serial port.

It might be useful to check that the serial connection does work with a terminal emulation program such as [minicom](https://alioth.debian.org/projects/minicom) (linux), or PuTTY (Windows). Once you have verified that a connection can be made and data transferred, you can be certain that you are connecting to the correct local port, that the port settings are correct, and that your serial cable is working properly.

Comment: The settings are correct. I just checked it with putty and it's connecting to the port properly...

Comment: How about flow control? Did you set hardware or software flow control when using putty (or was it set by default)? You could try setting RTSCTS by `ser.setRtsCts(True)`.

Comment: The default for the device was None. But even with the RTSCTS setting, nothing changed

Comment: When you tested with PuTTY, did you actually send the STX character, or did you just connect to the port? Back to Python, try flushing the serial port after writing STX, i.e. `ser.write(chr(2)); ser.flush()`. Another thing to try is to send a newline, so try `ser.write('\x02\n')`

Comment: i am not able to write inside the terminal. when i press the butttons of the keyboard, the putty terminal displays the corresponding Return for the serial device i am using (e.g. letters A, D, S return 1 or 0, other buttons return voltage values, etc). But therefore, i am not able to write statements in the terminal itself. will try to figure it out. But generally, the serial device should be working properly, has someone else has been using it until recently, just on another pc and with a different programming language than Python

Comment: Well, that's on a different PC, so there might be many differences. Can you run the other person's program on _your_ PC? I'm not sure that I follow your previous comment - are you able to connect with PuTTY and send a command to and receive a response from the remote device???? Until you have actually demonstrated that you can drive the remote device from _your_ PC, there remain questions about your setup. What happened when you tried to flush the port?

Comment: Thank you so much for patience. I am not a professional programmer. I can connect perfectly! I mean that when i am typing into the terminal of putty i am not able to write statements. if i press the button A for example, the terminal returns a 1, if i press the button Z for example, the terminal returns the measured voltage. But this corresponds with the settings of the device. But the flush command didn't help either. I am still trying out different things.

Comment: I don't think that i can install that program on my pc, since that program had to be specifically installed on the other pc for some reason (some memory thing, since the other program written in C+ for the development of video games/virtual realty tasks). That person is not around right now, so can't ask him.